# How to set ListView.builder inside a column in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview

I want to show List.builder inside a column, but if I add *List.builder* inside Column, it shows me an error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

In a list view, I pull the image from the API, but when I tried to add that *List.view* widget, it broke the layout.

Please see the image I attached:

[image: listview.builder error]

In the console, it gives an error of:

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#6c1e2 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE`
>
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':`
>
> Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'`

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/utils/widget_functions.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Notification.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/getwidget.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Sidebar.dart';
import 'package:mindmatch/screens/Footer.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mindmatch/utils/Auth.dart';
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

class Editprofile extends StatefulWidget {

    Editprofile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _Editprofile createState() => _Editprofile();
}

class _Editprofile extends State<Editprofile> {

    var UsrID = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');
    var data;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getData();
    }

    getData() async {
        //var res = await http.get(Uri(host: url));
        var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/index.php', {'act':'profile', 'UsrID': '${UsrID}'}));
        data = jsonDecode(res.body);
        //print(data);
        setState(() {});
        print(res.body);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        final ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
        final double padding = 25;
        final sidePadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding);

        //return SafeArea(
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              titleSpacing: 3,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0,
              title: Text('Edit Profile ${UsrID}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15,),),
              leading: Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                  width: 30,
                                  'assets/images/Menu.svg',
                                  height: 30,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () { Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
                              tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
                          ),
                      );
                  },
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                      child: Row(
                          children: [
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                  width: 30,
                                  'assets/images/search.svg',
                                  height: 30,
                              ),
                          ],
                      )
                  )
              ],
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),

          body: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topRight,
                      end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      //colors: const [Color.fromRGBO(132, 105, 211, 1), Color.fromRGBO(93, 181, 233, 1), Color.fromRGBO(86, 129, 233, 1)],
                      colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]
                  ),
              ),
              width: size.width,
              height: size.height,
              child: data != null?SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: sidePadding,
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ProfileImages(),
                          ],
                      ),
                  ),
              ): const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
          ),

          drawer: Sidebar(),

          persistentFooterButtons: [
              Footer(),
          ],
       );
    //);
    }
}

class ProfileImages extends StatefulWidget {

    ProfileImages({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _ProfileImages createState() => _ProfileImages();
}

class _ProfileImages extends State<ProfileImages> {

    var UsriD = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');
    var Imagedata;
    var img = "";
    var user = "";
    //var usrimgs = "";

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getImageData();
    }

    getImageData() async {
        var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', '/index.php', {'act': 'usrPhotos', 'Usrid': '${UsriD}'}));
        Imagedata = jsonDecode(res.body);
        print(Imagedata);
        setState(() {});
        print(res.body);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return
        Imagedata != null? ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: Imagedata.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Stack(
                    children: [
                        ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                            child:
                            Image.network(
                                "https://www.*******.net/files/images/${Imagedata[index]['image']}",
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                            top: 9,
                            right: 9,
                            child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {},
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    width: 30,
                                    'assets/images/close.svg',
                                    height: 30,
                                ),
                            ),
                        )
                    ],
                );
            }
            ): const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
     }
 }
```

My `ProfileImages` widget shows Listview.builder which has stored the images and I want to show that widget inside the column in `Editprofile` widget.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72879516/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the Listview builder axis direction is horizontal which requires a constrained height value to render the widget.

You can define a height for the container above the listViewBuilder.
And I could see there is a use of a stack inside the element of the listview builder, so try to give a constrained for that also if the error still persists.

Comment: thank you it solved my problem. but there is another error i see in my console i.e `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2` inline code `"https://www.algowid.net/mm_api/files/images/${Imagedata[index]['image']}",`

Comment: do you know anything abut this

Comment: In listView itemCount is given as the imageData.length but imageData is JsonObject so please cross check whether the jsonObject is a array.

Comment: `[{"id":"1","image":"abc.jpg"},{"id":"2","image":"xyz.jpg"}]` this is my Json response?

Comment: Please do check ImageData length before and after using it in the listViewBuilder. The value of the length is 2 when using it inside the listViewBuilder. For more accurate answer please do write a simple widget using the api call and share the code. let us debug it.

Answer (score 0):

When using scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, you need to use a specific height for that ListView. For that, you can wrap your Listview to

```dart
SizeBox(height: 100)
```

Comment: thank you it solved my problem. but there is another error i see in my console i.e `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2` inline code `"https://www.algowid.net/mm_api/files/images/${Imagedata[index]['image']}",` do you know anything about this

Answer (score 0):

Wrap ListView with an `Expanded` widget:

```
Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              itemCount: messageModel.list.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(messageModel.list.elementAt(index).message!),
                  subtitle: Text(messageModel.list.elementAt(index).user!),
                );
             },),
          );
```